# No match for 'operator>>' in my class member function, using set and get to read file input

Tags: c++, class, get, set, operator-keyword

So im trying to create a function that makes use of my set and get methods to read input from a file, into my class. I have to remove friendship from the following method: `friend istream & operator>>(istream & input, Date & D` and make use of my own get and set methods. This is what I have so far in the class I get the error in, Date.h

```
#if !defined(_DATE_H)
#define _DATE_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

class Date {
public:
    Date();
    Date(unsigned day1, string month1, unsigned year1);

    void SetDay(unsigned day1);
    void SetMonth(string month1);
    void SetYear(unsigned year1);
    unsigned GetDay() const;
    string GetMonth() const;
    unsigned GetYear() const;

    void SetDate(istream &input, Date & D);
    void GetDate(ostream & os, Date & D);


private:

    unsigned day;
    string month;
    unsigned year;

};

 ostream & operator <<(ostream & os, Date & D);
 istream & operator >>(istream & input, const Date & D);
#endif  //_DATE_H
```

And this is my .cpp file:

```
//
//
//  Generated by StarUML(tm) C++ Add-In


#include "Date.h"

Date::Date(unsigned day1, string month1, unsigned year1) {

    day = day1;
    month = month1;
    year = year1;

}


void Date::SetDay(unsigned day1) {

    day = day1;

}

void Date::SetMonth(string month1) {

    month = month1;

}

void Date::SetYear(unsigned year1) {

    year = year1;

}

unsigned Date::GetDay() const {

    return day;

}

string Date::GetMonth() const {

    return month;

}

unsigned Date::GetYear() const {

    return year;

}
istream & operator >>( istream & input, Date & D) {

    D.SetDate(input,D);
    return input;

}

ostream & operator <<( ostream & os, Date & D) {

    D.GetDate(os,D);

    return os;

}
void Date::SetDate(istream &input, Date & D){

    input >> D.SetDay(day) >> D.SetMonth(month) >> D.SetYear(year);
    input.ignore();

}

void Date::GetDate(ostream &os, Date & D){

    os << "  Date: " << D.GetDay() << " " << D.GetMonth() << " " << D.GetYear() << '\n';

}
```

I get the error `error: no match for 'operator>>' (operand types are 'std::istream {aka std::basic_istream<char>}' and 'void')|`. What does this mean and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement

```
input >> D.SetDay(day) >> D.SetMonth(month) >> D.SetYear(year);
```

makes no sense, since the functions doesn't return anything.

One way to solve your problem is to create temporary variables (e.g. `day`, `month` and `year`) and read into them. Then call the set functions separately passing the variables.

On another note, don't do `input.ignore()` in your input function (and don't print the newline in the output function), it's up to the user of the input/output functions to handle that.

Comment: Thank you, I now realize that it makes more sense to read the values into them after using temporary variables. And the input.ignore() was something I used to ignore the rest of the characters in the line because it was messing with my output previously, but I will take your advice and remove it.

Answer (score 1):

You are using your methods wrong.

```
void Date::SetDate(istream &input, Date & D){

    input >> D.SetDay(day) >> D.SetMonth(month) >> D.SetYear(year);
    input.ignore();

}
```

`D.SetDay` returns `void` and cannot be used like that. You could fix it like this:

```
void Date::SetDate(istream &input, Date & D){
    unsigned day_in;
    string month_in;
    unsigned year_in;
    input >> day_in >> month_in >> year_in;
    D.SetDay(day_in);
    D.SetMonth(month_in);
    D.SetYear(year_in);
}
```

However, there is reason to be that verbose. As `SetDate` is a member function it does not need to get passed a `Date` object and it can access private members directly:

```
void Date::SetDate(istream &input){
    input >> day >> month >> year;
}
```

The more idomatic way is to provide an `>>` overload as free function:

```
std::istream& (std::istream &in, Date& d){
    input >> d.day >> d.month >> d.year;
}
```

But you need to declare it as `friend` of `Day` so it can access private members.

PS: Only after writing this I noticed that you already have the overload as free function. Instead of making that call `SetDate` it can implement the input directly. Your `SetDate` does not add anything useful.

Comment: Thank you for response, and that's actually exactly what I had done initially, where I had the overload as a method of the class and as a friend. However, what Im trying to do now is remove that friendship and not make the overload a method of the class anymore, and try to achieve the same goal by using set and get methods. After using the temporary variables you suggested, im now getting this error: expected primary expression before '>>' token.  Thoughts?

Comment: Im under the impression that without the istream overload as a friend method, I cannot use this operator - '>>' and '<<'. How can I get around this?

Comment: @thedafferg what is wrong about making it a friend? If you don't need to make it a friend if you use temporaries and then the setters as in my first solution for the member

Comment: Nothing is wrong with it that I know of, however for my own sake and understanding of get and set I am trying to do it this way. I'm not very experienced and I'm just trying to make sense of these errors

Comment: @thedafferg getters and setters are a difficult topic. Maybe not that obvious, but they are rather controversial. In a sense they are a necessary evil. A common misunderstanding is that encapsulation == getters and setters, but more often than not getters/setters do break encapsulation. In your case, for example a setter for month should check that the value is `1 <= month <= 12`, thats what a setter can be used for, but writing setters only for their own sake is adding nothing but boilerplate